# Container Fechando no Docker

Tags: docker

Eu estou tentando rodar o otrs no docker e quando eu buildei o dockerfile ele reinicia o apache e fecha o container.

Segue o arquivo Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-perl2 libdbd-mysql-perl libtimedate-perl libnet-dns-perl libnet-ldap-perl \
    libio-socket-ssl-perl libpdf-api2-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libsoap-lite-perl libtext-csv-xs-perl \
    libjson-xs-perl libapache-dbi-perl libxml-libxml-perl libxml-libxslt-perl libyaml-perl \
    libarchive-zip-perl libcrypt-eksblowfish-perl libencode-hanextra-perl libmail-imapclient-perl \
    libtemplate-perl
RUN wget http://ftp.otrs.org/pub/otrs/otrs-6.0.17.tar.gz
RUN tar xzf otrs-6.0.17.tar.gz
RUN mv otrs-6.0.17 /opt/otrs
RUN apt-get install -y libdatetime-perl && apt-get install -y libauthen-ntlm-perl && \
  apt-get install -y libdbd-odbc-perl && \
  apt-get install libdigest-md5-perl
RUN useradd -d /opt/otrs -c 'OTRS user' otrs
RUN usermod -G www-data otrs
RUN cp /opt/otrs/Kernel/Config.pm.dist /opt/otrs/Kernel/Config.pm
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-perl2
RUN ln -s /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-httpd.include.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/zzz_otrs.conf
RUN a2enmod perl deflate filter headers
CMD service apache2 restart
WORKDIR /opt/otrs/
RUN ./bin/otrs.SetPermissions.pl
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Isso significa que a aplicação principal dentro do container está com erro, fechou e então o docker finaliza ele. Verifica o log da aplicação para maiores detalhes.

Comment: já revisei varias vezes e nada. :/

Comment: Docker só persistirá enquanto o processo de `CMD` estiver rodando. Quando o comando encerra, o Docker também derrubará a imagem criada. Neste caso, sua imagem é derrubada porque o comando `service apache2 restart` é finalizado. Para manter a imagem rodando você precisa manter o processo principal também rodando. Para o seu caso, mantenha o Apache executando em primeiro plano (*foreground*).

Comment: CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND, funcionou, brigado ai...